# FB.ui - Send dialog reappears after submitting

Tags: dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, send, fb.ui

We're seeing some strange behavior with Facebook Send dialogs (Javascript SDK, **FB.ui** method). After the Send button is clicked, the dialog disappears, then reappears. The dialog does disappear after a while without any user action, but this delay varies (anywhere from a split second to several seconds).

The messages are delivered without problems.

How to reproduce:

https://apps.facebook.com/barclays_pingit/

1. Click on "Send Message" under the "Tell a friend" title
2. Add a recipient and message
3. Click "Send"

Or:

1. Click on "Make your own video"
2. Choose a friend, how much they owe you, and for what
3. Click "Make video"
4. You can skip to the end of the video, then click "Send video to ..."
5. Add a message Click "Send"

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't give you the answer, but as I have the same problem, here is a quick patch:

```
       var callback = function callback(response) {
          var clear_callback = function(){
            $('.fb_dialog').remove();
          };
          var arr = [250,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,7000];
          for (var i in arr)
          {
            setTimeout(clear_callback,arr[i]);
          }
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
```